# How can I swap the axes on an eCharts bar chart with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, axes, echarts

I have created an eCharts barchart and I just want to swap the x and y axes

I have tried just swapping the data objects for the axes but that doesn't work and googling hasn't turned up much at all.

This is the initialisation script for the bar chart

```
var chart = echarts.init(document.getElementById('chart'));
var option = {
    yAxis: {
        name: '',
        data: ''
    },

    xAxis: {
        name: '',
        data: ["CARH"  , "CDFR"  , "HGA"  , "O2RG"  , "SHLA"  , "SHWS"]
    },

    series: {
        name: '',
        type: 'bar',
        data: [100.29, 101.05, 100.78, 96.3, 101.8, 99.9]
    }
};
chart.setOption(option);
```

Comment: Can you please provide an example so we can help you.

Comment: OK that's done now.

Comment: did you try this?  var option = {
    yAxis: {
        name: '',
        data: ["CARH"  , "CDFR"  , "HGA"  , "O2RG"  , "SHLA"  , "SHWS"]
    },

    xAxis: {
        name: '',
        data: ''
    },

    series: {
        name: '',
        type: 'bar',
        data: [100.29, 101.05, 100.78, 96.3, 101.8, 99.9]
    }
};

Comment: No that doesn't change the orientation of the bars, I want them to display horizontally rather than vertically

Answer (score 3):

It seems all the properties of `option` must be wrapped in arrays, and `xAxis` should be left empty:

```
option = {
    yAxis: [{
        name: '',
        data: ["CARH"  , "CDFR"  , "HGA"  , "O2RG"  , "SHLA"  , "SHWS"]
    }],

    xAxis: [{}],

    series: [{
        name: '',
        type: 'bar',
        data: [100.29, 101.05, 100.78, 96.3, 101.8, 50]
    }]
}
```

I found the solution by finding an [example of an echart horizontal barchart](https://gallery.echartsjs.com/editor.html?c=xAFYsB3sA4), and removing options that did not alter the "horizontalness" of the chart. Then I compared this minimal set of options to the one given in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var option = {
yAxis: [{
    name: '',
    data: ["CARH"  , "CDFR"  , "HGA"  , "O2RG"  , "SHLA"  , "SHWS"]
}],

xAxis: [{
    name: '',
    data: ['100.29', '101.05', '100.78', '96.3', '101.8', '50']
    }],

series: [{
    name: '',
    type: 'bar',
    data: [1  , 2  , 3  , 4 , 5  , 6]
}]
```

};